# Set default build system with Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2, build

I installed Sublime Text 2 on two machines: a not-so-old laptop running windows 8 and a much older laptop running windows xp. When I set a build system on the old laptop, it remembers my choice, and when I close sublime text and then open it again, the build system will be the same as when I closed sublime text. However, on my newer laptop, the build system is set to javaC every time I start sublime text. Since I don't use sublime text to program in java, I find this very annoying. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: I use custom buildfiles which don't have file-extensions coupled to them (I did this on purpose because I want to have multiple build processes for a specific extension). Also, this only works when Tools->Build System is set to Automatic. But it is set to javaC everytime I start Sublime...

Comment: Doesn't it automatically switch between build systems based on the file extension?

Comment: It does, but only when you set the options properly (I thought it was in the build file). I use custom build files and haven't done that. On purpose: in this case, I use asm files, and I have different build processes that I want to use (and it's not possible for sublime text to know which one to use).